# Shell script is not helping to kill tomcat application

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, sh, jenkins-groovy

I've to replicate behaviour of `CTRL+C` using shell script to turned down tomcat application server. Hence wrote following code in Jenkins pipeline script -

```
sh '''pgrep -fl catalina | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGINT'''
```

But it does not turn application down. However if I executed same command from terminal, it turns down the application -

```
pgrep -fl catalina | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGINT
```

Can you please help to understand what is wrong with shell script code?

Comment: ok try: `pkill -9 -f catalina`

Comment: I've tried `pkill -9 -f catalina`, `shutdown.sh` and `catalina.sh stop' are not helping to achieve what `CTRL+C` does. hence opted for `kill -SIGINT`

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat can write its process id to a PID file on startup if you tell it to. All you have to do is set the environment variable `$CATALINA_PID` to the path of the PID file.

For a vanilla Tomcat (started with `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`) this is done in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh`. This file might exist already if you've defined `$CATALINA_OPTS` with all of your favourite JVM command line options. If not, simply create it. It should contain a line which looks like this:

```
export CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/work/catalina.pid
```

I.e., my Tomcat is installed in `/opt/tomcat/`, and I've decided to put the PID file into the Tomcat work directory. You can put the PID file wherever you like, just be sure that the directory can be read and written to by the Tomcat user.

Using a PID file has some major advantages:

- On startup, Tomcat checks if the PID file already exists, and if it does, it refuses to start once more. This keeps you from accidentally running the same Tomcat instance with the same webapps twice.
- `shutdown.sh` can (and will) kill the Tomcat JVM process if it cannot issue a normal shutdown command, e.g. if it cannot connect to the Tomcat server port (8005 by default).

So maybe you don't need your shell any more...